# How to write script for systemd using different scripts

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

New to systemd here - essentially I have 3 different scripts: `activate.sh`, `toggle.sh`, and `deactivate.sh`. I want to use a systemd service and timer in order to do the following:

- When the service first starts, run `activate.sh` *once*
- Using the timer, I want to continuously run `toggle.sh` until...
- The service is stopped, in that case run `deactivate.sh`

I've tried experimenting with variations of `ExecStart`, `ExecStartPre`, `ExecStop`, `RemainAfterExit`, etc. but to no avail. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You should create three new unit files, something like these (untested):

`mything.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=My custom thingy

[Service]
Type=service
ExecStart=/path/to/activate.sh
ExecStop=/path/to/deactivate.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Wants=togglemything.timer
```

`togglemything.timer`:

```
[Unit]
Description=My custom timer thingy

[Timer]
OnCalendar=hourly
```

`togglemything.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Toggle my custom thing

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/path/to/toggle.sh
```

The last two must have the same name, before the dot, or else the timer won't do anything.

You only need to do `systemctl start mything` to set the ball rolling.